# python3 AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, attributeerror

[image]

I referred to every error cases and I checked the latest version of pyserial,
even if I remove all serial Lib(serial, pyserial), and reinstalled them, it still can't resolve this problem...

so I removed whole python and reinstalled for solving this issue, but it was same..

my python version is 3.7.1 (latest)
I couldn't find kind of my case, most of cases are version 2.x
please refer to the captured image that I uploaded it

if you have any good way to solve this issue, please let me know!

thank you.

Comment: You need to name your file something different than serial.py. It's importing itself.

Comment: @jordanm nice catch o.O

Comment: @jordanm Did you mean that I have to name the module name which is inside of "site-packages" to other one?  there are two similar module names "serial" and "pyserial-3.4.dist-info"